# Многопоточный сервер на PHP

Tags: php, потоки-данных, сокет

Собственно, решил написать такое чудо.
Разобрался с сокетами в PHP, естественно все это не проблема.
А вот как создать в PHP отдельный поток и пнуть ему клиента, почему-то не могу догнать. Подскажите пожалуйста.
Кроме того интересует, как быть с обработкой ошибок?

**UPD** (перенесу сюда): 
Вторая идея - обрабатывать все в одном потоке с очередью, но вот пока не известна ни длина очереди (теоретический максимум), ни размер передаваемых данных, ни период (теоретический минимум), через который будут появляться новые клиенты (чтобы рассчитать длину очереди).

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pcntl.php - юникс онли. Или я не понял вопроса?) Но многопоточные приложения на РНР, как по мне - это жестоко =D

Comment: Многопоточный или многопроцессный apache запускает php, который крутит скрипт, которым делает системный вызов и создаёт новый процесс, в котором запускается новый php и ему вручается другой  скрипт, который делает ошибку и делает системный вызов, чтобы написать в сокет, который слушает зависший первый скрипт, чтобы обработать ошибку...

Comment: Понятное дело, что это жестоко. Первая идея была написать на Java. Но не всегда это дело работает на хостингах, а выделенный сервер не каждому под силу купить.
Вторая идея, обрабатывать все в одном потоке с очередью, но вот пока не известна ни длина очереди (теоретический максимум), ни размер передаваемых данных, ни период (теоретический минимум) через который будут появляться новые клиенты (чтобы рассчитать длину очереди).

Comment: Python + Tornado web server! (Извиняйте за оффтоп, не сдержался)

Comment: Python - совершенно не знаю.
А насколько трудно найти хостинг с Tornado WS?

Comment: Да, Tornado придётся ставить. С хостингом - да, хз. Но торнадо написан на Python, и сервер прямо в вашем скрипте. Это почти то, что Вам нужно :)

Comment: Вот первая проблема это хостинг, иначе бы я делал бы все неделю назад на Java.

Comment: А он такой дорогой или редкий?

Comment: Вообще идея - минимизировать затраты на сервер, у заказчика пока каша в голове, вот приходится импровизировать.
Идеальная картина - сервер, который может работать на любом хостинге LAMP.
А если арендовать выделенный сервер, чтобы воткнуть туда Java приложение и LAMP для Front-end, даже не знаю во сколько это будет обходиться, так как предполагается не один такой сервер.

Comment: Месье знает толк!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. Ввиду того, что РНР запустить на постоянной основе (как сервис) достаточно затруднительно, можно применить несколько вариантов:

- Библиотека [Process Control](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pcntl.php) как раз для создания форков/потоков. Коими даже можно в некоторых пределах управлять.

Минусы: требует никсового сервера и оно по умолчанию не поставлено и необходимо иметь доступ к системе, чтобы его поставить. А такое не везде можно.

- Сделать цепную реакцию - каждый скрипт перед завершением запускает один или несколько новых скриптов в зависимости от условий... Получается такая независимая многопоточность. Управление параллельными потоками весьма затруднительно, хотя и возможно. Причём тут можно много вариаций - равноправные потоки, главный и второстепенный (т.е. вызываемый из главного и управляемый им без завершения главного), несколько главных, несколько второстепенных... В зависимости от архитектуры =)

Одна из схем мне представляется примерно такой: клиент тыкается в какой-то известный адрес, который прослушивается главным скриптом, скрипт смотрит - какие порты сейчас свободны, запускает второстепенный скрипт для клиента, который открывает соединение на свободном порту, отмечает в базе его занятость и передаёт клиенту сообщение, что всё хорошо - переткнись на новый порт. Где они и общаются. Как скрипт для клиента завершается (клиент ушёл или отвалился) - он закрывает сокет и сообщает, что порт освободился, и завершается. Опять же общаться можно между скриптами через базу, например. Через какую-нибудь очередь сообщений...

Минусы: жестоко и требует доступа к функциям системных вызовов. Опять же есть не везде.

Вариант самому написать расширение для потоков возможен, но относится к разряду мазохизма и не рассматривается =D

Хм, получается, что везде требуется определённый повышенный доступ к системе .-. А если он есть - проще уж писать на чём-то ином, чем так мучаться.

Comment: Соглашусь только с тем, что лучше писать на чем-то другом.
Но попрошу прокомментировать UPD.

Comment: Я тоже =) Остальное мне тоже ни капли не нравится и я бы так делать точно не стал)

Что именно из?)

Comment: Что думаете по поводу обработки в одном потоке всех, просто с очередью?

Comment: А, я не заметил. Хм, раз идёт один поток - единовременно общение будет ограничено только с одним клиентом. Как только нагрузка заметно увеличится - будет трубец. Но пока она будет меньше пары десятков запросов в секунду и передаваемые данные не превышают порядка десятков килобайт в секунду на клиента - особых проблем, думаю, не будет. Насчёт очереди - socket_accept имеет же собственную очередь?(могу и ошибаться - с сокетами не занимался) И создаёт новые независимые хендлы для общения с конкретным клиентом?

Comment: Да да, именно про эту очередь я и говорил.
Я думаю, что соединений может быть около 100-500 каждую секунду.
Данных не много, зависит от клиента, может, порядка нескольких сотен байт.

Comment: Хм, ну, на этот случай можно попробовать замутить тест =) Эмулятор клиентов на каком-нибудь сишарпе (ибо пишется быстро) в сотнях потоков будет пытаться общаться с сервером - передать ему вопрос и получить некоторый вычисленный ответ =) Хотя бы в самом простом случае - принять запрос, прочитать входные данные, обработать, ответить, закрыть и так далее.

А вот насколько велика очередь может быть - вот об этом я и понятия не имею .-. В документации не вижу, а в исходниках ковыряться - ну не знаю...

Comment: На первых парах стоит попробовать, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[pcntl_fork](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) - forks the currently running process.

Answer (score 0):

Кто мешает сделать несколько асинхронных http запросов с этому же серверу? Тогда апач сам будет выполять всю работу по многопоточности.  Ну а проблему синхронизации данных можно решить через локи файловой системы или пайпы.

Попробуйте например поиск по ключевым словах: asynchronous curl php, php filesystem locks, php pipes.

Comment: банально сделать скрипты-воркеры

Comment: Я не думаю, что Апач сумеет адекватно воспринять произвольную строку байт и передать ее PHP.

Comment: зачем апачу передавать строку байт?
я имею в виду, что этому же апачу(на котором уже работаешь) давать обычные асинхронные http запросы с помощью того же курла(или сокетов - не важно)к другим специальным скриптам(воркерам). параметры передавать через обычный пост и гет. результат(или ошибки) собирать в пайпе или в файле.
вот и все. вся многопоточность.

Comment: Вы, видимо, не до конца поняли мою задачу. У меня PHP должен обрабаотывать соединения через сокеты, а отсылаться ему будет просто массив байт. А запросов к самому Апачу не будет, т.е. сразу к сокетам все будет цепляться.

Comment: Т.е. основная проблема - это передача объекта сокета другому php скрипту через пост/гет параметры? Собственно сокет уже есть на этом компе, просто другому скрипту нужно как то его идентифицировать/открыть.
Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу php+share+sockets+between+process
дает один из вариантов решения.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/178411-share-socket-resource-between-processes/
Хотя здесь творчеству нет предела ;)

Comment: Основная проблема это реализация всего этого функционала на любом сервере с PHP. Т.е. использование дополнительного процесса не желательно:

1. Так как не на любом хостинге можно иметь возможность пользоваться `exec`
2. А как такая структура поведет себя при тысячах запросов в секунду?

Comment: 1. exec не нужен. асинхронный http запрос к этому же серверу так же запускает новый экземпляр желаемого скрипта.(очень часто там, где нет exec - там же нет и сокетов кстати)
2. все впирается в синхронизацию. файл дергать - это ясно что смерть.  если найти способ быстрой передачи сокета через пайп или что-то похожее, то проблем не будет. рабочий процесс: один поток - один клиент.  так же вполне возможно создать какой-нибудь пул сокетов. тогда тоже будет прирост производительности.
на этом наш диалог можно считать завершенным. а сюда я пришел сказать, что движение анонимус - это хуита ;)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, @Dex нужно обрабатывать запросы не по HTTP протоколу, а по какому-то своему через сокеты напрямую. А apache и прочие веб-сервера понимают исключительно HTTP, потому и не подходят.